# Chrome 97 DevTools Suddenly Displaying Styled Components?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Chrome v97.0.4692.71 is suddenly displaying the following styled component tag as the last line in the `<head>` section of every web page:

```
<style data-styled="" data-styled-version="4.4.1"></style>
```

Does anyone know why this is being displayed?  This only happens for publicly-accessible web pages, not web pages in my localhost website dev environment.  I've checked this on other non-development machines that I own and the above tag is not being displayed.

Comment: Probably added by a chrome extension.

Comment: I only have 9 extensions loaded and they've all be very reliable.  But, at your suggestion, I turned them all off then turned them on one-by-one.  To my surprise my NewsGuard extension was adding the style tag!  Thanks, wOxxOm, for the suggestion!  If you would move your comment to an Answer, I'll award the Answer to you.